# Correct datatype to use for Type mappings?

Tags: c#

I'd like to implement a basic mapping system similar to AutoMapper, but all explicit mappings, no convention-based mappings.

To do this I've written a class that is supposed to maintain a register of "mapping" functions and look them up on demand in order to map one type to another. The usage I'm envisaging is like this:

Somewhere in startup:

```
Mapper.Register<TypeA, TypeB>(typeA =>
{
    var typeB = new TypeB()
    {
        Property1 = typeA.Property1
    };

    return typeB;
}
```

And then when I want to perform the mapping...

```
TypeA typeA = new TypeA();
TypeB typeB = Mapper.Map<TypeA, TypeB>(typeA);
```

Currently I've used a `Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Delegate>` to store this mapping register, but it's not working as I had hoped...

```
public static class Mapper
{
    private readonly static Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Delegate> Mappings = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Delegate>();

    public static void Register<TSource, TDestination>(Func<TSource, TDestination> mappingFunction)
        where TSource : class
        where TDestination : class
    {
        Delegate mappingFunc;

        if (Mappings.TryGetValue(new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof (TSource), typeof (TDestination)), out mappingFunc))
            Mappings[new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof (TSource), typeof (TDestination))] = mappingFunction;
        else
            Mappings.Add(new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof (TSource), typeof (TDestination)), mappingFunction);
    }

    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource src)
        where TSource : class
        where TDestination : class
    {
        Delegate mappingFunc;

        if (!Mappings.TryGetValue(new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof (TSource), typeof (TDestination)), out mappingFunc))
            throw new Exception("Invalid mapping: no mapping found for requested types.");

        var func = mappingFunc as Func<TSource, TDestination>;

        if (func == null)
            throw new Exception("Invalid mapping: no mapping found for requested types.");

        return func.Invoke(src);
    }
}
```

When this code is used, registering the mappings works fine, but retrieving them from the dictionary fails, and I think it's because of the third line in the `Map` method:

```
Mappings.TryGetValue(new Tuple<Type, Type>(typeof (TSource), typeof (TDestination)), out mappingFunc)
```

This line always fails to pass the test, and I *think* if I understand correctly, it's because Tuple is a reference type, so a new instance of `Tuple<Type, Type>`, regardless of what `Item1` and `Item2` are, will *never* match any key in the `Dictionary`.

**So, `Dictionary<Tuple<Type, Type>, Delegate>` is not appropriate for storing this mapping register. In that case, what data type is?**

Comment: How does it "fail to pass the test"?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that the "if" statement always returned false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to run your above code, I get the result I expect:

```
Mapper.Register<string, Regex>(s => new Regex("not using the given string"));
Mapper.Register<string, Regex>(s => new Regex(s));
var regex = Mapper.Map<string, Regex>(@"\w*");
// regex is now the Regex object instantiated with @"\w*"
```

In other words, your code seems to be functioning correctly.

> This line always fails to pass the test, and I think if I understand correctly, it's because Tuple is a reference type, so a new instance of `Tuple<Type, Type>`, regardless of what `Item1` and `Item2` are, will never match any key in the `Dictionary`.

Actually, the implementation of `Tuple` does support what you are trying to do. The `Dictionary` uses `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods under the hood to make lookups. The `Equals` method usually checks reference equality for objects, but the `Tuple` [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs) shows that it is specifically programmed to use structural equality:

```
    public override Boolean Equals(Object obj) {
        return ((IStructuralEquatable) this).Equals(obj, EqualityComparer<Object>.Default);;
    }

    Boolean IStructuralEquatable.Equals(Object other, IEqualityComparer comparer) {
        if (other == null) return false;

        Tuple<T1, T2> objTuple = other as Tuple<T1, T2>;

        if (objTuple == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return comparer.Equals(m_Item1, objTuple.m_Item1) && comparer.Equals(m_Item2, objTuple.m_Item2);
    }
```

A `Dictionary` is the right way to go for this use case, as an arbitrary number of registration can be made and we would like to ensure fast lookup. I think, however, that I would probably still create my own type `TypeMapping` to use for the `Dictionary` instead of `Tuple<Type, Type>`, because I think tuples do not express the intend/usage. Just remember to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` so it functions correctly with `Dictionary` like so:

```
public class TypeMapping : IStructuralEquatable
{
    public Type From { get; private set; }
    public Type To { get; private set; }

    public TypeMapping (Type from, Type to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ((IStructuralEquatable) this).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<Object>.Default);
    }

    int IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comparer)
    {
        var hash = 17;
        unchecked
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + From.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + To.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        return ((IStructuralEquatable) this).Equals(obj, EqualityComparer<Object>.Default);
    }

    bool IStructuralEquatable.Equals(Object other, IEqualityComparer comparer) {
        if (other == null) return false;

        var otherMapping = other as TypeMapping;
        if (otherMapping == null) return false;

        return comparer.Equals(From, otherMapping.From) && comparer.Equals(To, otherMapping.To);
    }
}
```

And then you would have your `Dictionary` in the Mapping class look like this (with corresponding changes to `Registration` and `Map` methods):

```
private readonly static Dictionary<TypeMapping, Delegate> Mappings = new Dictionary<TypeMapping, Delegate>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the approach I ended up taking and it's working well.

Comment: @NickCoad I just added sample code for the `TypeMapping` if you are interested.